# Rails creating duplicates when editing nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I did a lot of googling, and all come back to adding :id to the  permitted attributes, but that doesn't work in my case so:
How can i prevent multiple empty rows (in related tables)from being created when editing a nested form? 
Every time i eddit a form, it doubles the amount of empty related records.

The controller:

```
    class EnquiriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource
  # before_action :set_enquiry, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  #11-1-2017 Devise geinstalleerd, nog verder afmaken!(oa onderstaande uncommenten)


  # GET /enquiries
  # GET /enquiries.json
  def index
   # @enquiries = Enquiry.all
    @enquirie = current_user.enquiries
  end

  # GET /enquiries/1
  # GET /enquiries/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /enquiries/new
  def new
    @enquiry = Enquiry.new
    @enquiry.enquirymeasures.build
       #@enquiry.measurements.build
   @enquiry.tools.build
    @enquiry.build_applicant
    @enquiry.signatures.build
    @enquiry.gasmeters.build
       #@enquiry.enquirymeasures.build.build_measurement
  end

  # GET /enquiries/1/edit
  def edit
    #nog op kunnen slaan!!!! 1-01-17 Marco
    @enquiry = Enquiry.find(params[:id])
    @enquiry.enquirymeasures.build

    @enquiry.tools.build
    @enquiry.build_applicant
    @enquiry.signatures.build
   @enquiry.gasmeters.build

  end

  # POST /enquiries
  # POST /enquiries.json
  def create
    @enquiry.user_id = current_user.id
    @enquiry = Enquiry.new(enquiry_params)
    #@enquiry.enquirymeasures.build

    respond_to do |format|
      if @enquiry.save
        format.html { redirect_to @enquiry, notice: 'Enquiry was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @enquiry }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @enquiry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  #approved_enquiry_notification

  # PATCH/PUT /enquiries/1
  # PATCH/PUT /enquiries/1.json
  def update
    @enquiry = Enquiry.find(params[:id])
     respond_to do |format|
      if @enquiry.update(enquiry_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @enquiry, notice: 'Enquiry was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @enquiry }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @enquiry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /enquiries/1
  # DELETE /enquiries/1.json
  def destroy
    @enquiry.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to enquiries_url, notice: 'Enquiry was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

   private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_enquiry
      @enquiry = Enquiry.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  #25-1 MG alle attributes hadden ook :id
    def enquiry_params
      params.require(:enquiry).permit(:id, :reference, :location, :description, :date, :amount, :approved, enquirymeasures_attributes: [:id, :responsible, :done, :needed, :measurement_id, :user],
                                      tools_attributes: [:id, :handtool, :other, :motorvehicle, :compressor, :ramp, :scaffold, :crane, :ladder, :generator, :tankladder],
                                        applicant_attributes: [:id, :name, :email, :contractor_id],
                                      signatures_attributes: [:id, :date, :signature, :representative_id],
                                      gasmeters_attributes: [:id, :date, :tester, :signature, :oxigen, :o_needed, :o_continu, :explosives, :e_needed, :e_continu, :mat1, :mat1_needed, :mat1_continu, :mat2, :mat2_needed, :mat2_continu, :mat3, :mat3_needed, :mat3_continu],
                                      controls_attributes: [:id, :enquirycheck, :workspacecheck, :enquiry_id]).merge(user_id: current_user.id)


    end



end
```

The models:
main:

```
class Enquiry < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enquirymeasures, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :enquirymeasures, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:responsible].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true


  has_many :tools, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tools

  has_many :controls, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :controls

  has_one :applicant, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :applicant

  has_one :contractor, through: :applicant

  has_many :signatures, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :signatures
  has_many :representatives , through: :signatures, :source => :representatives

  has_many :gasmeters, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :gasmeters

  belongs_to :user

  #voor de goedkeuring mail
  after_create :send_confirmation_mail
  def send_confirmation_mail
    ModelMailer.new_enquiry_mail(self).deliver
  end

  #after_update :send_approved_mail
  #def send_approved_mail
   # if params[:approved] == '1'
  #  if :approved == '1'
  #  ModelMailer.enquiry_approved_mailer(self).deliver
  #  end
  #end

end
```

one of the related models:

```
class Tool < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :enquiry
end
```

I didn't include the entire _form because it is very long(300 lines) but to give you a idea:

```
 <div class="form-group ">

        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

          <%= f.fields_for :applicant do |a| %>

              <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                      <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        Aanvraag
                      </a>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                      <%= f.label :Referentie, :class => "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
                      <%= f.text_field :reference, :class => "form-control" %> <br>

                      <%= f.label :Locatie, :class => "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
                      <%= f.select :location, [['Chemiepark', 'chemiepark'], ['Winschoten', 'winschoten'], ['Farmsum', 'farmsum']], :class => "form-control" %>
                      <br>
                      <br>

                      <%= f.label :Omschrijving, :class => "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
                      <%= f.text_area :description, :class => "form-control" %> <br>

                      <%= f.label :Aantal_uitvoerenden, :class => "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
                      <%= f.number_field :amount, :class => "form-control" %> <br>

                      <%= f.label :Datum %><br>
                      <%= f.datetime_select :date %> <br>

                      <%= a.label :Aanvrager %><br>
                      <%= a.text_field :name %> <br>

                      <%= a.label :email %><br>
                      <%= a.text_field :email %> <br>

                      <%= a.label :Aannemer %><br>
                      <%= a.collection_select(:contractor_id, Contractor.all, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

          <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `reject_if` clauses to each of the nested attributes, or, if you don't want the form to silently reject the nested attributes, then you can add validation to each of the individual models for the required fields; which will kick back errors for whatever you've specified as required.

```
has_many :tools, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :tools, reject_if: :all_blank

has_many :controls, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :controls, reject_if: :all_blank

has_one :applicant, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :applicant, reject_if: :all_blank

has_one :contractor, through: :applicant

has_many :signatures, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :signatures, reject_if: :all_blank

has_many :representatives , through: :signatures, :source => :representatives

has_many :gasmeters, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :gasmeters, reject_if: :all_blank
```

On a side note, I've found the [`cocoon` gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) to be extremely helpful when working with nested forms.

Comment: Thanks, i tried your sollution,, it almost gave the right results, so i tweaked it a bit and now it seems to work. i changed the all_blank to :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:handtool].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true using a required field per table. , so for gasmeters it's [:tester] etc Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
def update
  @enquiry = Enquiry.find(params[:id])
  if @enquiry.update_attributes(enquiry_params)
    # Handle a successful update.
  else
    render 'edit'
end
```

and remove id from enquiry_params.

Comment: remove every :id from the enquiry_params? just tested it withoud the :id for the main table and your if @enquiry.update_attributes(enquiry_params) instead of what i had, but without succes. it still adds 1 record per nested table

Comment: You shouldn't need to accept id in nested params or build any new models when updating since it is just updating existing records.  So I think removing all id's from nested params would help.